# How to make a cell reference never change

Tags: google-sheets

So I have an google spreadsheet, I am build a cache stats page, that just caches other sheets in the document. All the other sheets are constantly changing.

Here is an example.

I have 2 sheets in a workbook.

SheetA and SheetB

SheetA has 1 column 1 row. A1 and in A1 we have a value of lets say $50.00

SheetB has the same thing, 1 row 1 column. A1 has a formula of ='SheetA'!$A$1

If I go into SheetA and add a column to the left of A1, Google Spreadsheet updates my formula to be ='SheetA'!$B$1

I was under the impression with the $ (dollar) sign the reference should not change but it does. Any ideas on how to prevent Google from updating my formulas? Currently anytime I update the sheets I have to run a script to update all the formulas back to the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping that in an indirect function. That should prevent the 'shifting'.
=INDIRECT("'SheetA'!A1")